# Make 24 using exactly three 3s

Tags: formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

**Make 24 using exactly three 3s**

Each number formed with a 3 and the 24 in the equation are all base 10.

You cannot introduce any additional digits or constants.

Plus(+), negation/subtraction (-), division(/ or show it with a fraction bar), multiplication(* or use grouping symbols as appropriate), exponentiation(^ or show it with an exponent). regular factorial(!), square root(sqrt(), or the radical symbol), grouping symbols such as parentheses and/or square brackets, and the regular decimal point(not for the repeating decimal) are allowed.  No concatenation of any type is allowed.

No other functions/operators are allowed.  This includes floor and ceiling functions not being allowed. (edit)

I am looking for a total of **10** solutions.

Comment: Let's please *not* make "non-serious" or otherwise very clearly non-pertinent answers here. They do not attempt to answer the posed puzzle, and will be deleted: puzzles with no [tag:lateral-thinking] tag do not invite such answers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ten solutions.

> (i) $\sqrt{3^{3!}} -3 = 24$ 
>  (ii) $\left(\frac{3! + 3!}{3} \right)! = 24$ 
>  (iii) $ \left(\frac{3}{.3} - 3! \right)! = 24$ 
>  (iv) $\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{.3} + 3!} \right)! = 24$ 
>  (v) $\left(3! - \frac{3!}{3} \right)! = 24$ 
>  (vi) $(3\times 3!)+3! = 24$ (Pugmonkey) 
>  (vii) $(3 + \frac{3}{3})! = 24$ (Weather Vane) 
>  (viii) $3^3 - 3 = 24$ (Olive) 
>  (ix) $(\sqrt{3})^{3!} -3 = 24$ (Rupert) 
>  (x) $(3+(3−3)!)! = 24$ (Trenin)

Comment: @WeatherVane Just saw yours.

Comment: Yours are prolific.

Comment: @ hexomino - Please see my note to Weather Vane.   Your first three listed are basic/primitive/elegant ones.  Keep those.

Comment: @OliveStemforn Ah, okay, will remove.

Comment: @ hexomino - With your fourth solution posted, I just edited my problem statement, and I am now looking for a total of 10 solutions (including the one I posted).

Comment: Ha! Just beat me to (v). Can I propose we use this as the definitive answer for when @OliveStemforn gets back?

Comment: @RupertMorrish you changed the order, which in order of posting was Olive(1), me(1), Pugmonkey(1), hexomino(3), you(1), hexomino(2)

Comment: Yes, because some of the comments here reference the order in which they were added

Comment: I guess #10 is $(3+\frac{.3}{.3})!$ or $(3+\frac{3!}{3!})!$

Comment: @JonathanAllan Not sure, we tried a variation of that earlier and were told it wasn't allowed. Actually, your second suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's what Olive's comment above was referring to.

Comment: @JonathanAllan the similar variant $(3 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}})! = 24$ was banned too.

Comment: I see that the (v) solution is the newest one on this page for me to read, as well as confirm.

Comment: I'd say that i and ix are basically the same since the order of applying the square root and the power are irrelevant in the same way that 3x2 and 2x3 are the same (though that is just my subjective opinion).

Comment: Is there a reason for both the factorial and the sqrt in (i), considering they cancel out, wouldn't it be more elegant without either?

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman This would make it equivalent to (viii) which was the first solution posted and I wanted to find one that was structurally different.

Comment: @Chris Yes I think you are right here, not sure if we really can consider them to be different considering what has been disallowed previously.

Comment: I see, and since it's more of a numerical "fluke" (in that it would only work for 3) that they cancel that stops them being classed as identical I guess.

Comment: @hexomino: I guess we wait for Olive to give the word of god.

Comment: A)  Again, (paraphrasing), in (i) and (ix), removal of the square root symbols, respectively, leads to expressions that are not equivalent to 24.  They are needed.  A square root of 3 divided by a square root of 3 in a formerly posted solution shows those square roots don't need to be there, for example.  B)  (i) and (ix) get to 24 by different routes.  (i) starts with an integer, raises that to an integer, then takes the square root of that, etc., whereas (ix) starts with an irrational number, raises it to an integer producing an integer, then takes the square root of that result, etc.

Comment: @ Weather Vane - Several yellow boxes below user Trenin posted one for it.

Comment: @OliveStemforn Can't believe I missed that one.

Comment: @OliveStemforn: I don't agree with you but it is a subjective thing and its your question so your rules. :) Thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: @ Chris - If you want to eliminate either (i) or (ix), then I support you. You'll have nine solutions.  Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

(edit) I will post **one** of the 10 solutions as an example:

> $3^3 - 3 = 24$

Comment: This solution came to mind after reading just the title of the question. I assumed it was the only one.

Answer (score 13):

Here is my first:

> $(3 + \frac{3}{3})! = 24$

Comment: @ Weather Vane - Let us say that by adding the square root symbols, you have not changed the values of those.  They are redundant.  It's similar to writing 1! instead of 1 or 2! instead of 2.  Although mathematically correct, I would not see them as "primitive solutions."

Comment: Ah OK, I was about to add another similar variant - removed.

Answer (score 11):

Tenth solution from hint

> $$\left(3+(3-3)!\right)!$$

Comment: Thank you for this tenth solution.  Is it not ironic how relative the lack of complexity this solution has, given the amount of time between its posting and the original problem?

Comment: Nice work,can;t believe I missed this.

Answer (score 10):

Here is one possible solution:

> $3\times3!+3!$

Answer (score 8):

> $(\sqrt{3})^{3!} -3 = 24$

Which is obviously only slightly different to hexomino's:

> (i) $\sqrt{3^{3!}} -3 = 24$

Comment: Ah, yes, good spot!

Comment: @ Rupert Morrish - Good, your first one listed is a definitely newer type, because, for instance, if the square root symbol were to be dropped, the expression would have a different value.

Comment: @OliveStemforn: But the order of powers (which square root basically is) is unimportant (ie $a^{b^c} = a^{c^b}$) so are these two really different? To me it feels like it is the same principle as $3\times3!+3!$ being different from $3!+3\times3!$ - its exactly the same operations, just in a slightly different order...

Comment: @chris The order of powers is definitely important.  $2^{3^5} \ne 2^{5^3}$  The first is $2^{3^5} = 2^{243}$.  The second is $2^{5^3}=2^{125}$.  Perhaps you mean $(a^b)^c = (a^c)^b$.

Comment: @Chris Because that is more applicable to this case anyways because  $\sqrt{3^{3!}}= (3^{3!})^{\frac{1}{2}}=(3^{\frac{1}{2}})^{3!}=(\sqrt{3})^{3!}$.

Comment: I did mean that, apologies.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like something should be able to be done with

> $\frac{(3!)!}{30} = 24$

with judicious use of

> decimal points

but I can't find it.

> $\frac{(3!)!}{3^3 + 3} = 24$

uses 4 3s.

Comment: :: : I will have to leave this computer in about five minutes from now (for up to as long as 20 hours later on) before I post for confirmations of remaining solutions.